# Show that solutions of differential equation has horizontal asymptote

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*Show that all solutions of differential equation
$$ x' = \left( \frac{x^2+1}{t^4+1} \right)^{1/3}$$
have two horizontal asymptotes.*

Obviously, the derivative is positive everywhere, so it is sufficient to show that all solutions are bounded. However, i have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: separate the variables. Send $t\to\infty$. Observe that one of the integrals converges. Conclude. Send $t\to-\infty$...

Comment: So the second one has to be to. But this implies that the range of x has to be bounded, because otherwise it wont converge. Thanks.

Comment: What is the downvote for?