# prove all solutions of differential equation have 2 horizontal asymptotes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove, very carefully, that the following ODE
>
> $$ \frac{ \mathrm{d} y }{\mathrm{d} x } =  \sqrt[3]{
>  \frac{y^2+1}{x^4+1} } $$
>
> have ${\bf two}$ horizontal asymptotes.

This question was in my exam. This was my attempt:

If $y(x)$ is a solution curve, we know it will have an horizontal asymptote if 
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) = C $$

and when the slope tends to zero. So, we want

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}   \sqrt[3]{
 \frac{y^2+1}{x^4+1} } = 0 $$

but this is always true so we must have horizontal asymptotes.

This seems reasonable enough but got the problem wrong and no points awarded. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Can you show that $y^2$ grows/falls slower than $x^4$?

Comment: The first mistake is thinking that if $f(x)\to C$ as $x\to\infty$ then $f'(x)\to 0$. This need not be true. Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin(x^2)$, where $f\to0$ but $f'$ has no limit as $x\to\infty$. The second mistake is that your calculation of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{dy}{dx}$ unclear: $y$ is a function of $x$, so you must explain how you know $dy/dx$ tends to zero as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: [See here for a solution to the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660707/show-that-solutions-of-differential-equation-has-horizontal-asymptote) (though this doesn't exactly answer what you did wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
y' = C\to y_{\infty} = C x + b\to C = \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{\frac{(Cx+b)^2+1}{x^4+1}} = 0
$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You give no argument to show that

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}   \sqrt[3]{
 \frac{y^2+1}{x^4+1} } = 0 $$

"is always true". This is why you deserve no points.